# Bash session errors on commands: "fork: Cannot allocate memory"

Tags: linux, centos, memory, out-of-memory

I have a bash session open to a remote server and something is wrong. I created a directory "test" and touched the files inside `touch 1 2 3 4 5`. I then tried to copy the directory `cp test/ test2/` and it hung. Killed it with ^C; entered the directory and tried to `cp 1 2`; it hung as well.

I then tried to do a ls and got the following error:

`-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory`

Now, I know that there is memory available. I logged in from another terminal which defaults to my home directory. `touch 1` and `cp 1 2` and it hangs. I can `ls` though..

Logged in as root and tried to `cp 1 2` from the same directory and it works. No problems from the root account.

Lots of memory free:

```
#free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           188G         87G        3.4G        1.8G         97G        3.3G
Swap:          3.9G        3.8G        140M
```

I've still got the other ssh session which is giving my allocation errors opened for testing. What is going on?

**Update 1**

I tried running `cp 1 2` from the terminal that I can still from commands from but hangs and then `top -b | grep -w bash` from my root accout. The `cp` command never shows.

The other terminal which was reporting memory allocation problems is now responding to `ls` but still hangs with `cp 1 2`.

**Update 2**

The problem was a misconfiguration in the shared .bashrc:

```
function cp() {
   cp --preserve=all --no-dereference $@
}
```

Whereas it should have been setup as:

```
alias cp='cp -adR'
```

Comment: Try running the same commands and in a separate SSH session run top while the command is running. That should give you an idea as to whats happening. Can you post your results in your question?

Comment: Updated the original question.

Comment: Run `strace cp 1 2` and see where something goes wrong. Or run `strace -f -p1234` from another terminal where 1234 is the PID of the bash process where you get the errors, and then run `cp 1 2` in that bash process.

Comment: Can you try `type cp` and see that you are accessing the appropriate version.  Possibly, you can also issue the absolute path of `cp` in the command.

Comment: Brownie points to `unxnut` for helping track down the snafu. `type cp` pointed directly to the erroneous function. Resubmit as an answer and I'll accept it. Gilles answer was also good but strace called the program `cp` instead of the bash function and exited fast and cleanly with no hang and still left me hunting.